# convert Data from Database to excel

Tags: php, mysql

i have grid that gets data from data base like this :-

```
      <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" class="gwlines">
      <tbody><tr>
        <th width="15">#</th>
        <th width="150">Name</th>
        <th width="100">Type</th>
        <th width="50">Date</th>
        <th width="50">From</th>
        <th width="50">To</th>
        <th width="30">Price</th>
        <th width="30">Paid</th>
        <th width="30">Remaind</th>
        <th colspan="4">Actions</th>
      </tr>
  <?
    $i=1;
    while($objResult=mysql_fetch_array($objQuery)){
  ?>              
      <tr id="vip_row<?=$objResult["vip_id"];?>" <? echo ($i%2==0?'bgcolor="#edf0f6"':''); ?>>
        <td><input name="cbSelect[]" type="checkbox" id="cbSelect[]" value="<?=$objResult["vip_id"]; ?>" /></td>
        <td><?=$objResult["customer_name"]; ?></td>
        <td><?=$objResult["vip_type"]; ?></td>
        <td><?=$objResult["vip_date"]; ?></td>
        <td><?=$objResult["vip_from"]; ?></td>
        <td><?=$objResult["vip_to"]; ?></td>
        <td><?=$objResult["vip_price"]; ?></td>                
        <td><?=$objResult["vip_paid"]; ?></td>
        <td><?=$objResult["vip_remind"]; ?></td>
        <td width="16"><a href="index.php?body=edit_vip&id=<?=$objResult["vip_id"];?>" original-title="Edit and View VIP Information"><img width="15" height="15" class="tabpimpa" alt="picture" src="images/edit.png"></a></td>
        <td width="16"><a href="#" onClick="delete_vip('<?=$objResult["vip_id"];?>');" original-title="Delete VIP"><img width="15" height="15" class="tabpimpa" alt="picture" src="images/delete.png"></a></td>
        <td width="16"><a href="print_single_bills_vip.php?id=<?=$objResult["vip_id"];?>" target="_new"><img width="15" height="15" class="tabpimpa" alt="picture" src="images/print.png"></a></td>
        <td width="16"><a href="#" onClick="vip_to_egypt('<?=$objResult["vip_id"];?>');"><img width="15" height="15" class="tabpimpa" alt="picture" src="images/sms.png"></a></td>
      </tr>

<? ++$i; } ?>
</tbody></table>
```

this grid will get data from data base, and i want to export this result data to excel.

how can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

try using [phpexcel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Examples)

happy coding :)

**EDIT: "phpexcel" is a  project providing a set of classes for the PHP programming language, which allow you to write to and read from different spreadsheet file formats, like Excel (BIFF) .xls, Excel 2007 (OfficeOpenXML) .xlsx, CSV, Libre/OpenOffice Calc .ods, Gnumeric, PDF, HTML, ... This project is built around Microsoft's OpenXML standard and PHP.**

-by phpexcel site

Comment: Can you elaborate? _How_ should phpexcel be used?

Comment: Stuart M : Project providing a set of classes for the PHP programming language, which allow you to write to and read from different spreadsheet file formats, like Excel (BIFF) .xls, Excel 2007 (OfficeOpenXML) .xlsx, CSV, Libre/OpenOffice Calc .ods, Gnumeric, PDF, HTML, ... This project is built around Microsoft's OpenXML standard and PHP.
-by phpexcel site

Comment: Cool, I was just reviewing this answer since it was flagged for review for being too short in length. Your comment would be great to add to the answer itself, by editing it!

Answer (score 0):

Following from http://support.microsoft.com/kb/165499 you should be able to just save the HTML table and open it in excel!

It will of course drop most of the formatting and the functions, but most of the time that is not a real concern when exporting data to excel.

Answer (score 0):

try the solution to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3830411/save-mysql-query-to-excel-file-from-php-webpage). But if I where you, don't just convert it to excel if you want to print it. You can use pdf like [this](http://www.tcpdf.org/) and [this](http://www.fpdf.org/).